# Open, select and add a .jpg file inside a form

Tags: c#, winforms

How to open, select and add a only jpeg format file inside a form in c# from any directory of computer? Here is the code.

```
private void open2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
    string Chosen_File = "";    
    Chosen_File = openFileDialog1.FileName;          
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Insert an image";   
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    openFileDialog1.FileName ="";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "JPEG Images|*.jpg|GIF Images|*.gif|All Files|";
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        Chosen_File = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Chosen_File);

    }
 }
```

Comment: its only open the format of picture not loading inside the form

Comment: i dont see any problem with your code,it works

Comment: it will not display the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove first openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        string Chosen_File = "";
        Chosen_File = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Insert an image";
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "JPEG Images|*.jpg|GIF Images|*.gif|All Files|";
        //openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            Chosen_File = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Chosen_File);

        }
    }
```

Exept this, your code works well!

Comment: works fine but when i place the picture box in middle , it will not show the image

Comment: What you mean place the picture box in middle?

Comment: I'm making a paintbox, it works fine i use a panel inside a form , when i clicked on new menu it shows panel box perfectly , but on same case i also use a text box same overlap at panel when i clicked on text editor button it will no show the editor in middle where panel also place, but when i place text box at right side it will show text box, same problem with picture box.

Comment: I am sorry, but I barely understand what you're trying to say. Can you show your code or/and your designer screen shots. Maybe one of your panels is hiding an another one...

Comment: PictureBox is into the panel? It seems that the panel is hiding the pictureBox when you turn it to visible

Comment: picture box or text editor were place as same location of panel location. there are three button for them, when i press new it show panel on the location but when i press text editor button it will not show the text editor on the location of panel

Comment: If the order of buttons clicking changing the behaviour? It seems that controls are hiding each other. For a testing, locate them in different locations and check the functionality...

Comment: i locate them in different location when they work perfectly but it will not be good,

Comment: Ok. That confirm that I was right, the panel hides a picture box! You need to hide the panel (or other control) when you want do show text editor or pictureBox. For example: You want to show picture box: first of all hide the panel and text editor and then show the picturebox. Make only one of 3 controls is visible at one time

Comment: yes you are right, but i don't know understand what i'm doing now :(

Comment: it will no show panel when i click text editor button but it will no also show text editor when i place it same location as panel

Comment: In the block of code that I posted in my answer add 2 commants in the beggining: YourPanel.Visible = false; YourTextBox.Visible.False. Do same things in code block that shows rest controls

Comment: What the Panel do? Maybe you can locate one, always visible panel, and add/remove the controls to it when needed: MainPanel.Controls.Add (myPictureBox) and MainPanel.Controls.Remove(myTextBox)

Comment: have you account on facebook?

Comment: Here i can not show my design pictures because it will not allow me

Comment: send me to lev@inz.org.il

Answer (score 1):

You have one `openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();` to many. Delete the first one and use just the one inside the `if` clause!  The `if` clause then uses the result after displaying the Dialog. I also prefer to explicitly checking for `DialogResult.OK` but that should not make a difference..

Your code shows the Dialog window twice, doesn't it? (It certainly does!) If you pick the image to display on the first dialog you will get the dialog a second time and then have to OK it there, too. If you cancel the second dialog nothing will show.

The Result i.e. the user's choice is only returned directly from the Show(); if you don't grab it there it is lost! This is different from the content of the choice, fields of the Dialog (e.g. the filename), which are all there afterwards..

Comment: i don't know what are you saying :(

Comment: `openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)` You open/show the filedialog twice!